# UIVisualEffectsView changes hue when selected

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a UITableCell with a UIVisualEffectView inside.

I am using the .Dark blur effect of the UIVisualEffectsView.

Looks fine:
[image]

Tapping on the cell to select it is a UI feature (brings up modal to change account info).

When the cell is selected, the hue of the blur changes to something lighter.

[image]

When the cell is de-selected, it goes back to the normal hue.

I have tried using the .Light and .ExtraLight blurs, and all have the same result.  Interestingly, the 'selected' blur hue is always the same, and it is none of Dark, Light, or ExtraLight.  Looks to be just a blur with no hue change at all (which I understand is supposed to be what Light is, but trust me, they look different).

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can get it to stop?

Comment: Is it really the "hue" that changes? As in, (for example) red to blue?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView, by default, changes the colour of cells when they are selected.  You can disable this per cell, or for the whole table view simply by changing Selection Style to None in the storyboard.

**Edit:**  To change this programatically, call

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```